# MySQL Inner Join Query: incorrect output

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query and i am using inner join in the query. Due to some unknown reason it is not working as i expected. I am not sure what is wrong with the query. Can anybody advise me what am i doing wrong.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT f.uid, a.uid, b.uid, c.uid,
       d.uid, e.uid,
       f.date, a.email, a.fname, a.lname,
       a.mobile, a.pic, a.address
FROM   users a 
inner join friends b 
inner join exp c 
inner join skill d 
inner join personaldetails e 
inner join jobs f 
    on a.uid = b.uid =c.uid = d.uid=e.uid=f.uid 
where f.job_id= 22 
    and f.ignored=0 
    and a.fname like '%Rah%' 
order by f.date DESC
```

If i run this query then i suppose i would get `a.uid =1, b.uid =1, c.uid =1, d.uid=1, f.uid =1`

But i am getting `a.uid =1, b.uid=10, c.uid=10, d.uid=1,e.uid=1,f.uid =1`

Comment: Thanks for down vote. i would love an explanation. So, that i will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a weird issue, I've just tried something below.

```
select 1=10=10=1=1=1 from dual;
```

result is **0**,

```
select 10=10=1=1=1=1 from dual;
```

result is **1**, maybe `on a.uid = b.uid =c.uid = d.uid=e.uid=f.uid` this query condition take the second one as its compute result. I'm not sure if mysql do some kind of optimized step to cause this issue when excuting.

I think when mysql compute `a.uid = b.uid` if a.uid and b.uid both is 1, it comes out a value 1 means `true`, so only if c.uid is 1 then the computing will go on about d.uid, e.uid, f.uid.

Anyway, try this, may help you;)

```
select f.uid, a.uid, b.uid, c.uid,
   d.uid, e.uid,
   f.date, a.email, a.fname, a.lname,
   a.mobile, a.pic, a.address
from users a, friends b ,exp c, skill d, personaldetails e, jobs f  
where f.job_id= 22 
and f.ignored=0 
and a.fname like '%Rah%'
and a.uid = b.uid
and b.uid = c.uid
and c.uid = e.uid
and e.uid = f.uid 
order by f.date desc
```

If you've found some other explanation, share to me plz;)

Comment: You are correct. I also found that. a=b=c is not working in this case. Voted up and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried splitting it up?

```
select f.uid,a.uid,b.uid,c.uid,d.uid,e.uid,f.date,a.email,a.fname,a.lname,a.mobile,a.pic,a.address
from users a 
    inner join friends b on (a.uid = b.uid)
    inner join exp c on (b.uid = c.uid)
    inner join skill d on (c.uid = d.uid)
    inner join personaldetails e on (d.uid = e.uid)
    inner join jobs f on (e.uid = f.uid)
where f.job_id= 22 and f.ignored=0 and a.fname like '%Rah%' order by f.date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if there are some duplicates in one of the tables. I am sure that it is the case. If the following query returns a record, then you will have the culprit.

```
SELECT f.uid, a.uid, b.uid, c.uid,
       d.uid, e.uid,
       f.date, a.email, a.fname, a.lname,
       a.mobile, a.pic, a.address
FROM   users a 
inner join friends b 
inner join exp c 
inner join skill d 
inner join personaldetails e 
inner join jobs f 
    on a.uid = b.uid =c.uid = d.uid=e.uid=f.uid 
where f.job_id= 22 
    and f.ignored=0 
    and a.fname like '%Rah%' 
group by f.uid, a.uid, b.uid, c.uid,
       d.uid, e.uid
having count(*) > 1
order by f.date DESC;
```

Comment: I run the query no records return.

Comment: I would try debugging this by commenting one clause at a time. @CalculatingMachine - Do try.